# Bubbling errors upstream in async message-based services

Tags: microservices, error-handling, message-queue, client-server, async

Imagine a simple set up of an API and a 2nd service, where the API pushes some msgs to the message queue and the service pulls them and processes them.

[image]

Now, if an error occurs while processing a msg, there's no straightforward way of sending the error upstream to the API, so it can bubble it up to the client.

The first and most straightforward approach I can think of is pushing the error to the message queue, with some unique ID, so the API can pick it up and recognize what request is the error about. The API can store such errors in cache (or some other temp storage) and the the client can occasionally request the API for "are there any errors from my requests?".

I was wondering if there's a better/smarter/cleaner approach to this, that someone has as an experience under their belt.

Answer (score 2):

Say your first queue contains requests to frobnicate certain foos. Each message in there needs a unique identifier. Best would be something natural (like the ID of the foo that should be frobnicated).

To handle success/error feedback you add a second queue, e.g. `foo-frobnication-results`. When a foo has been frobnicated, you push e.g.

```json
   {
     "fooId": 1233457,
     "success": true
   }
```

And when the frobnication failed, you push

```json
   {
     "fooId": 1233457,
     "success": false,
     "error": "whatever data is needed to describe the error"
   }
```

The service that sent the frobnication request can then listen to this new queue and handle errors.
This has the added benefit that a third service could now hook into the existing process and do it's own thing for successfully frobnicated foos.

---

Snarky side comment: when you want an asynchronous/Event-Driven system, totally strike the concept of "regularly checking" from your mind. Tell, don't ask. A cronjob is inferior to a message queue in almost all situations. And an unnecessary cronjob in an otherwise async system is a real bad code smell.